# Фиксированное меню при прокрутке страницы

Tags: navigationbar, css

Здравствуйте, уважаемые HashCoderы.

Вопрос в том, что бывает меню, которое при скроллинге прилипает к верхней части сайта! Как такое реализовать на [этом примере](https://jsfiddle.net/1jc0gzry/)? Помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут глянь](http://pcvector.net/scripts/layout_and_interface/390-lipkiy-header.html)

Comment: Помогло! Спасибою

Comment: На здоровье. Удачи

Answer (score 0):

Нужно на джаваскрипте добавлять класс, когда проскролили высоту шапки.

И уже в css дописывать position:fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $block = $('#block'); // ID шапки

    if($(window).scrollTop() > $block.offset().top) { // Тут идея в том, что блок привязывается к верху, как только "прилипает" к верху окна браузера. Замените $block.offset().top на любое значение и получится, что когда вы проскроллили на большее кол-во пиксейлей, чем указали, добавиться класс к шапке.
        $block.addClass('fixed'); // Добавляем класс fixed. В стилях указываем для него position:fixed, height и прочее, чтобы сделать шапку фиксированной.
    } else {
        $block.removeClass('fixed'); // удаляем класс
    }
});
```

Разумеется, в CSS нужно написать стили для класса fixed, чтобы зафиксировать нужный вам блок.